# How to obtain slice plots from x,y,z,v data?

Tags: matlab, slice, mesh, volume

I would like to use `Slice()` function for obtaining figures like this [image: figure], following the code:

```
[x, y, z] = meshgrid(-3:0.25:3);
v = x.*exp(-x.^2 - y.^2 - z.^2);

slice(x, y, z, v, [], 0, 0);
colorbar;
```

Nevertheless, my value `v` is not a function of my x,y,z meshgrid, my v value is an scalar independent of x,y,z coordinates.

Is there any way of obtaining a v value on the space, knowing only x,y,z coordinates + a v value associated to those coordinates?

Comment: The title of your question ask how to do a slice plot but in the question you are actually asking how to obtain `v` ... that is quite different. Is `v` calculated? measured ? acquired from a file ?

Answer (score 0):

Try **griddata**

```
xr = linspace( min(x),max(x),10 );
yr = linspace( min(y),max(y),10 );
zr = linspace( min(z),max(z),10 );
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(xr,yr,zr);
V = griddata(x,y,z,v,X,Y,Z);
slice(X,Y,Z,V,[],0,0)
```